# Examine query generated from MongoDB projection by C# driver

Tags: mongodb-csharp-2.0

I'm querying data with C# driver for mongodb using projection. The code is like:

```
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("_id", userId);
var projection = Builders<User>.Projection.Expression(u => Tuple.Create(u.UserId, u.UserName));
var cursor = await collection.Find(filter).Project(projection).ToCursorAsync();
```

How do I check the query generated by the C# code?